# Debugging a Laravel 5 artisan migrate unexpected T_VARIABLE FatalErrorException

Tags: debugging, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

When running `artisan migrate` on a Laravel 5 project, it is failing with the following `FatalErrorException`:

> $ artisan migrate -vvv --force
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]   syntax
>   error, unexpected '$table' (T_VARIABLE)

How do I get the file and line that is causing the error?

If in anyway relevant, I'm on a Windows 7 x64 machine with WAMP - PHP 5.6 and Laravel Framework version 5.1.10 (LTS).

Comment: Having the same problem. I have triple checked my migration files. They run on local machine but error on remote :(

Comment: @Sisir try running php lint recursively to have it check for any syntax errors, you could use https://gist.github.com/mathiasverraes/3096500 (if on windows, you can run it with http://www.mingw.org or git-bash)

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec php -l {} \; |grep -v "No syntax errors detected"` is a one-liner you could use for the same - credit: https://gist.github.com/k3n/1846220#gistcomment-2148283

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> **There might be a semicolon or bracket missing a line**

**`Check all in your migration files.`**

> **Laravel is configured to create daily log files for your application**
>   **which are stored in the storage/logs directory.**

**http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#logging**

Comment: I did go through them manually, and I couldn't find the error, so I was wondering if there is a log file somewhere or a command-parameter that'll give me the full-stack-trace or the file and line where this error stems from.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wish it would show you the error reported in the log file when you use artisan for migrations.

Answer (score 0):

This class **Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException** has some differences compared with the other Exception classes and it is not properly presented by the "error renderers" or "error notifiers".

A New **sentry** "error notifier" (**"getsentry/sentry-php"** version >= "2.0") will give you a proper stack trace.

- Here is issue where is reported : https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/issues/761
- Here is the PR for fix : https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-php/pull/763